# SQLAlchemy select with all many to many relationship objects as list

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Given this Many to Many relationship:

```
tagmap = db.Table('tagmap', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'),)

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id    = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text  = db.Column(db.Text)
    tags  = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tagmap, backref='posts')

class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    id    = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name  = db.Column(db.String)
```

How would you construct a query to select all the Posts including an iterable list of associated Tag objects?

Desired query result structure:

```
[ <Post 1, "Blah",      [<Tag "Goober">, <Tag "Mexico">]>,
  <Post 2, "Daft Punk", [<Tag "French">]>,
  <Post 3, "Slurpee",   [<Tag "Diabetes">, <Tag "Tasty">, <Tag "Sugary">]>,
  <Post 4, "Lasers",    []> ]
```

Example desired result usage in a Jinja template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.text }}
    <hr>
    {% for tag in post.tags %}
        {{ tag.name }}, 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Edit**:

When trying to extend the query, the tags stop being included. See failed query below:

```
Post.query.join(User)\
    .options(db.joinedload(Post.tags))\
    .order_by(Post.create_date.desc()).limit(5)\
    .values(User.name.label('author'),
            Post.create_date,
            Post.text,)
```

**Edit 2**:

So this query works great:

```
posts = db.session.query(Post, User.name.label('author')).join(User)\
            .options(db.joinedload(Post.tags))\
            .order_by(Post.created.desc()).limit(5)
```

but if I want to be selective about the columns in Post I select:

```
# I only need the post text, nothing else
posts = db.session.query(Post.text, User.name.label('author')).join(User)\
            .options(db.joinedload(Post.tags))\
            .order_by(Post.created.desc()).limit(5)
```

It begins to fall apart quickly:

```
ArgumentError: Query has only expression-based entities - can't find property named 'tags'.
```

So I try to add the tags back:

```
# Yes, I know this is wrong
posts = db.session.query(Post.text, Post.tags, User.name.label('author'))\
            .join(User)\               
            .options(db.joinedload(Post.tags))\
            .order_by(Post.created.desc()).limit(5)
```

Which still fails.

So if you only want specific columns from the parent object (Post), where to you say in the expression, "I still want the tags"?

It's not really that important now, but I figured it would be useful to know. Or even know that it's not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you want to use **eager loading** for relationships.  You can achieve that either by setting `lazy` keyword argument in your relationship to `'joined'` or `'subquery'`:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    # ...
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tagmap, backref='posts',
                           lazy='joined')    # Or lazy='subquery'
```

Or you can set it per query:

```
q = Post.query.options(db.joinedload(Post.tags)).all()
# Or db.subqueryload(Post.tags)
```

Refer to [Eager Loading](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#joined-eager-loading) part of ORM tutorial and [Relationship Loading Techniques](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html) for more details.

Comment: How would you include the `joinedload` statement in a more complex query, for instance one using `.values()`? (I've updated my question with an example query.)

Comment: Well, first of all you're not using `Post.tags` in your `values()` arguments, although I don't think it would work with a relationship, at least it doesn't in a quick test with my other code. If you want to query values from multiple tables, wouldn't using `db.session.query(...)` be better in this case?

Comment: I mean, `Post.query` is a short form of `db.session.query(Post)`. Since you want to query more than `Post` objects, you should be using the `db.session.query` form.

Comment: Well I managed to get my query working. However, what I was wondering is when you want to choose the individual columns of the parent object, the joinedload objects stop being included. See updated question above.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to come up with something working, but failed. I don't think that relationships can be used in queries like this at all, though I might be wrong. As I see it, you can only query mapped object (and use eager loading to populate its relationships) or individual columns and expressions. Maybe someone more knowledgeable in SA will step up and prove me wrong (or confirm my observation).

Answer (score 0):

SQLAlchemy auto-loads the `post.tags` property when you access it, so you only need to load all the posts you want.

`db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('quotes.id'),)`

Is that `quotes.id` a typo?

Comment: Yes that was a typo, I've corrected the Foreign Keys so that they make sense now.